# Error 500 with save() method of eloquent/laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I want to save an object with Laravel's `eloquent` but I get error 500 when trying to save.

This is my model code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Categorie extends Model
{

}
```

and this is my action:

```
public function addCategorie() {
    $input = Input::all();
    $categorie = new Categorie;
    $categorie->libelle = $input['label'];
    $categorie->save();
    return $categorie;
}
```

When I use `print_r($categorie)` after the save method I get a result, but when I use the `save()` method I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `categories` (`libelle`, `description`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (sss, zzz, 2015-12-23 16:20:30, 2015-12-23 16:20:30 ))

Comment: yes it is .. column not found ..

Comment: This error means that you are missing this column in your database. When you make your migration you should include $table->timestamps(); to your migration to add these two fields to your table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your migration file for `categories` table, you need to have

```
Schema::create("categories", function($table){
  // Id, name, etc
  $table->timestamps();
}
```

so that `eloquent` queries can update when this entry was created and saved, or `created_at` and `updated_at`. If you don't want to use these timestamps, add

```
class Categorie extends Model {
  public $timestamps = false;
}
```

to your `Categorie` model.